# Best file format for Image search

Tags: images, search-engines, google-search

Which image file format is recommended to be used for best results from image search engines, eg, Google Image ?

Comment: @DavidPostill if it is off topic, then why not migrate to proper SE site ?

Answer (score 1):

When an image is uploaded to Google image search it is processed to get a profile and then that profile is compared to other profiles of images. So the format makes little difference; PNG, JPGE, GIF, TIFF, etc… The format does not matter.

But what *does* matter is size, quality and resolution. The better of all/any of those and the better the results. As explained [in this Google post on the topic](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2011/06/search-by-text-voice-or-image.html):

> Search by Image starts with the computer vision technology underlying
>   Google Goggles, and adds new techniques and functionality that
>   optimize the experience for desktop. The technology behind Search by
>   Image analyzes your image to find its most distinctive points, lines
>   and textures and creates a mathematical model. We match that model
>   against billions of images in our index, and page analysis helps us
>   derive a best guess text description of your image. Search by Image
>   technology also includes the ability to match against images on the
>   web so that we can show you similar images and webpages that contain
>   your image.

Additionally, at one point Google used humans—acting as “mechanical Turks”—to help classify images in the form of a game [simply known as “Google Image Labeller”](https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/006066.html) but that was [taken offline back in 2011](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-image-labeler-dead-14663.html). Meaning that image quality as it displays in the browser—or is parsed by Google’s system—would be the main criteria used to provide a decent image search results.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a "Best" file format for images when it comes to search engines. Typically file formats that will show up most often would be JPG and PNG. Unless you search specifically for a different image format, will you get them. So I guess you could say the best would be either JPG or PNG.